# TextField is not showing chinese text in iOS

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, ios11

I have an issue with textfield with Chinese input,I have enabled keyboard to china language, keyboard is showing with Chinese letters but the letters selected are not shown in the textfield.

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. Show your code and your current setup.

Comment: Issue fixed @the4kman, but other thing is i want to add Chinese characters to string for string operations like string separation and joining